# Удалить последний коммит

Tags: git, git-commit

Можно ли удалить свой последний коммит? Если да, какую команду надо ввести?

Comment: Детальный ответ для разных возможных случаев: [Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431521/181472)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для отката последнего локального коммита используйте [`git reset`](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-reset.html). Для отката коммита, который вы запушили на сервер, используйте [`git revert`](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-revert.html).

Comment: Для чайников `git revert HEAD`