# Вернуться на нужный коммит

Tags: git, git-commit

Есть у меня проект, я внес в него изменения и теперь он не компилируется. Я хочу, откатиться на нужный мне коммит. Иными словами мне нужно что бы изменения в моих файлах на пк, пришли к тому виду как были в нужном мне коммите. Как это сделать?

**Git Log:**

```
commit b7521fb90a8225a4f97a591c596556bd180132f1
Author: SonyAimbo <******@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Sep 15 13:55:25 2016 +0300

    Добавлена подержка GCC 4.9

commit 53d1bb31b554d1422661e4f4a71f77582e33fea4
Author: SonyAimbo <******@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Sep 15 03:16:43 2016 +0300

    Включил Gentle Fair Sleepers

commit 2b1535103118c52ff80199d1c688966bd783d1b3
Author: SonyAimbo <******@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Sep 15 01:25:12 2016 +0300

    Небольшие правки в конфиге
```

Мне нужно откатиться до этого `53d1bb31b554d1422661e4f4a71f77582e33fea4` коммита.

[Вот](https://github.com/SonyAimbo/Kernel/commits/master) мои коммиты, при этом я хочу удалить коммиты начиная с [этого](https://github.com/SonyAimbo/Kernel/commit/31a3e1e161fdaf9ee8679e840bab13176aed0380).

Comment: Чтобы откатиться к коммиту используйте команду: git checkout 53d1bb31b554d1422661e4f4a71f77582e33fea4 По поводу удаления уже писали об этом [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/216804/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82)

Comment: Посмотрите на ответ тут, вам нужен пункт 4 или 5. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431521/181472

Answer (score 2):

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Удалит с концами, применяется при каких-то очень крупных косяках. Судя по истории как раз на 1 коммит нужно.

```
git checkout 53d1bb31b554d1422661e4f4a71f77582e33fea4
```

Просто мягко перенесет на этот коммит.

Comment: Можно ещё после мягкого еще запушить форсом, тоже убьёт коммиты выше

Answer (score 0):

просто удалить коммит нельзя. То есть можно, но тогда перестроятся все последующий коммиты. Поэтому, используется технология revert - то есть, накатываение "коммита наоборот". Делается это в консоли командой `git revert <sha хеш коммита>`. Если нужно несколько коммитов откатить - применяйте последовательно.

Да, в истории будет "откат коммита такого то". Но это нормально.

При откатывании коммита возможны конфликты. Их нужно будет решать.

В своем вопросе Вы пишете "откатиться до коммита" и "удалить коммиты". Определитесь:)